# Whats the best way to insert selected checkboxes data in database in symfony2 doctrine

Tags: php, forms, symfony, checkbox, doctrine

I have a table called 'Tasks', and 'User' has a Many-to-Many relation with tasks.

On the page I am showing:

`<input type="checkbox"  name="tasks[]" value="task.id">   TaskName`

`<input type="checkbox"> name="tasks[]"   TaskName2`

`<input type="checkbox"> name="tasks[]"  TaskName3`

I want to know: On the server side, how can I get the array of checkboxes which were selected by the user?

If I get the collection then I can add it, using

`User->addTasks(tasks)`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are using Symfony's built-in forms functionality. I'd highly recommend looking into it...

With Symfony forms, you can show entities as checkboxes by setting both of the "expanded" and "multiple" options each to `true`:

```
// StackOverflow\BulbasaurBundle\Form\TrainerType.php

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class TrainerType extends AbstractType
{
    ...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add(
                'pokemon',
                'entity',
                array
                (
                    "class" => "BulbasaurBundle:Pokemon",
                    "expanded" => true,
                    "multiple" => true,
                    "property" => "description"
                )
            );
    }

    ...
}
```

When this form is rendered, it will display each of the Pokemon entities as checkboxes, using the `__toString()` method as the checkbox's label.

An added bonus to using Symfony forms is that Symfony will manage which boxes are checked automagically. The form acts as the intermediary between the entity and the request/views. That is, when you make a request to change the object, the controller creates a form based on that object's current state, and presents it to the user. Conversely, when the user submits that data, the controller can bind the request information to the entity, and can then persist it.

More information on Symfony2 forms here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: I tried that but my only problem is how can i display the `description` stored in pokeman entity as label next to each checkboxes

Comment: Change the `__toString()` method:

`public function __toString()
{ return $this->getDescription(); }`

Comment: Actually, just add a new element to that options array: "property" = "description". This overrides the `__toString()` method and uses the `getDescription()` method instead.

Comment: I tried that and i got his `The option "property" does not exist. Known options are: "attr", `

Comment: Can you post your code for the `$builder`? Also, out of curiosity, what version of Symfony are you using? It appears that it should work on any 2.0+, but I wonder if this part is newer...